# PHP if statement when reading a file from Pastebin somehow doesn't work

Tags: php

So I wrote some PHP code that reads a file from Pastebin and loops through it. My Pastebin file looks like this:

```
=WRTSAM=
=Dutch=
=English=
+ Hond
- Dog
+ Eend
- Duck
+ Schaap
- Sheep
+ Kat
- Cat
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$pb_key = $_GET['list'];

$listfile = file('https://pastebin.com/raw/' . $pb_key);

foreach ($listfile as $line_num => $line) {
    if ($line_num == 0) {
        echo $line;

        if ($line == "=WRTSAM=") {
            echo "It works!";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The weird thing is that is does work for the lines starting with a minus. Could it have something to do with Unicode/ASCII?

Sorry for the (probably) stupid question, but I just can't figure it out. I've been trying random stuff for like an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `file()` includes the newlines in each string, but the string you're comparing with doesn't have a newline. If you don't want this, use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINE` option:

```
$listfile = file('https://pastebin.com/raw/' . $pb_key, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One thing: it's `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`, not `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINE`. Could you please edit your comment for others with the same problem?